# after retired or after retirement or after retiring？

Tags: grammar

I am preparing a speech about the life after retire. But not sure which one is correct below, please help to confirm.
1. After retire, I want to be a happy person.
2. After retirement, I want to be a happy person.
3. After retired, I want to be a happy person.
4. After retiring, I want to be a happy person.

Comment: 1,2,3 are incorrect.  It’s either 4 or “In retirement I want to be ...”

Comment: @Jim sorry to put this question in a wrong discuss section.i shoud ask this in English language learners.

Answer (score 0):

1. Incorrect. Here's what's acceptable:

> Once I've retired, my goal is to be a happy person.

2. Too macabre. It means "Once my retirement is over, I want to be a happy person."
3. Incorrect. The correct way of putting it would be:

> After I retire, I want to be happy.

4. Awkward. A more natural way of putting it would be:

> In retirement, I would like to be as happy as possible.